# Implementing Uniswap v3 API single swap example on scaffold-eth - ERROR: cannot estimate gas

Tags: ethereum, solidity, uniswap

Using [scaffold-eth](https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth) to implement this single swap example from the [uniswap documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/single-swaps).

Pretty much just copied and pasted the code and was able to deploy it successfully to rinkeby:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';

contract YourContract {
  // For the scope of these swap examples,
  // we will detail the design considerations when using
  // `exactInput`, `exactInputSingle`, `exactOutput`, and  `exactOutputSingle`.

  // It should be noted that for the sake of these examples, we purposefully pass in the swap router instead of inherit the swap router for simplicity.
  // More advanced example contracts will detail how to inherit the swap router safely.

  ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;

  // This example swaps DAI/WETH9 for single path swaps and DAI/USDC/WETH9 for multi path swaps.

  address public constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
  address public constant WETH9 = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
  address public constant USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;

  // For this example, we will set the pool fee to 0.3%.
  uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;

  constructor(ISwapRouter _swapRouter) {
      swapRouter = _swapRouter;
  }

  /// @notice swapExactInputSingle swaps a fixed amount of DAI for a maximum possible amount of WETH9
  /// using the DAI/WETH9 0.3% pool by calling `exactInputSingle` in the swap router.
  /// @dev The calling address must approve this contract to spend at least `amountIn` worth of its DAI for this function to succeed.
  /// @param amountIn The exact amount of DAI that will be swapped for WETH9.
  /// @return amountOut The amount of WETH9 received.
  function swapExactInputSingle(uint256 amountIn) external returns (uint256 amountOut) {
      // msg.sender must approve this contract

      // Transfer the specified amount of DAI to this contract.
      TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(DAI, msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);

      // Approve the router to spend DAI.
      TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

      // Naively set amountOutMinimum to 0. In production, use an oracle or other data source to choose a safer value for amountOutMinimum.
      // We also set the sqrtPriceLimitx96 to be 0 to ensure we swap our exact input amount.
      ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params =
          ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams({
              tokenIn: DAI,
              tokenOut: WETH9,
              fee: poolFee,
              recipient: msg.sender,
              deadline: block.timestamp,
              amountIn: amountIn,
              amountOutMinimum: 0,
              sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
          });

      // The call to `exactInputSingle` executes the swap.
      amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
  }

  /// @notice swapExactOutputSingle swaps a minimum possible amount of DAI for a fixed amount of WETH.
  /// @dev The calling address must approve this contract to spend its DAI for this function to succeed. As the amount of input DAI is variable,
  /// the calling address will need to approve for a slightly higher amount, anticipating some variance.
  /// @param amountOut The exact amount of WETH9 to receive from the swap.
  /// @param amountInMaximum The amount of DAI we are willing to spend to receive the specified amount of WETH9.
  /// @return amountIn The amount of DAI actually spent in the swap.
  function swapExactOutputSingle(uint256 amountOut, uint256 amountInMaximum) external returns (uint256 amountIn) {
      // Transfer the specified amount of DAI to this contract.
      TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(DAI, msg.sender, address(this), amountInMaximum);

      // Approve the router to spend the specifed `amountInMaximum` of DAI.
      // In production, you should choose the maximum amount to spend based on oracles or other data sources to achieve a better swap.
      TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountInMaximum);

      ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params =
          ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams({
              tokenIn: DAI,
              tokenOut: WETH9,
              fee: poolFee,
              recipient: msg.sender,
              deadline: block.timestamp,
              amountOut: amountOut,
              amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
              sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
          });

      // Executes the swap returning the amountIn needed to spend to receive the desired amountOut.
      amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params);

      // For exact output swaps, the amountInMaximum may not have all been spent.
      // If the actual amount spent (amountIn) is less than the specified maximum amount, we must refund the msg.sender and approve the swapRouter to spend 0.
      if (amountIn < amountInMaximum) {
          TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), 0);
          TransferHelper.safeTransfer(DAI, msg.sender, amountInMaximum - amountIn);
      }
  }
}
```

Also learned to edit my deployer to add in the args for the constructor, and made sure to pass the SwapRouter address from [here](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments):

```js
await deploy("YourContract", {
    // Learn more about args here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-deploy#deploymentsdeploy
    from: deployer,
    args: [ '0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564' ],
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: 5,
  });
```

This all worked, and I am able to see this in the debug console on my local scaffold-eth, running on rinkeby:

[image]

I also made sure to have enough funds in my wallet for gas, etc:

[image]

When I try to hit send in the swapExactInputSingle function for any amount of DAI, I get the following error every time:

```
{
   "reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit",
   "code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT",
   "error":{
      "code":-32000,
      "message":"execution reverted"
   },
   "method":"estimateGas",
   "transaction":{
      "from":"0xF59FBfd44C9e495542D46109F81416bd3fC38Ed7",
      "to":"0xcFc57b48365133105F6877a02126673B7b906a55",
      "data":"0x73bd43ad000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a",
      "accessList":null
   }
}
```

I get this error as soon as I hit send, and am never prompted to approve my DAI or anything else. Other simple contracts have worked and I am able to send transactions on Rinkeby properly, so assume this is due to the added complexity of using the Uniswap API, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The recipient is not msg.sender, it should be address(this). Also you have to take care of the functions TransferHelper, who is going to receive, who is going to send.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try setting your config to look like this. I believe the issue you are experiencing is caused by `metamask` improperly estimating gas

```
networks: {
  hardhat: {
   
   forking: {
      url: `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/YOUR_KEY_HERE`,
      // url: `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_KEY}`,
      // url: 'http://localhost:8545',
    },
    gasPrice: 0,
    initialBaseFeePerGas: 0,

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The token address of DAI, WETH9, USDC are of the Ethereum mainnet and you have deployed it on Rinkeby. You have to use the token contract address of Rinkeby.

Not sure about any other issues if present.